# Oauth Codeigniter API

Tags: api, codeigniter, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0

Ok i have a project where i need to build a api oauth and to be honest i am completely lost and confused and really in need of some advice to help me get started.

The service i have allows users to create apps which will then generate two keys and store them into a database.

My database has table called apps with 4 fields.

```
name (VARCHAR 250)
description (TEXT)
key (VARCHAR 250)
secret (VARCHAR 250)
```

So the user create a app like below.

```
name = 'myapp';
description = 'Access to my api';
key = '5788334367';
secret = '91708741625783470472';
```

Now here is the part where i am completely lost building the api with oauth. I want to use https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver as i have work with it before to build a api but it was a open api only running get requests and just for me a single user so no apps.

Correct me if i am wrong, oauth is just a framework that you will include like any other library where do i find a oauth library that fit with codeigniter.

I found this which explains the process quite well and has helped http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/oauth but like everything only helps me so far.

The process i have for the api (i think).

When i am a user using my api, they will send of the key and secret to my api.
My api takes the two keys via a oauth endpoint from my codeigniter oauth library via post method checks them against the database and sends a token back which my user can then access the api with.

Just really trying to get started my process please help.

1. Install codeigniter
2. Include codeigniters rest api library
3. Install a oauth library
4. Setup a function within the oauth library to check my users app keys against the database to check they are valid and return a token
5. Start to build out the api with endpoints and calls like /api/list_files

My users can then use other frameworks to access my api.

Would love some help to get me of the ground i am completely new to building a full oauth api.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find how to do it then?